# Question about DynamicModule

Tags: function-construction, dynamic

I have a such custom function:

```
MyCopy := DynamicModule[{from, to},
  Print@Grid[{{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from], "Directory"], 
      Dynamic[from]}, {FileNameSetter[Dynamic[to], "Directory"], 
      Dynamic[to]}}, Alignment -> {Left}];
  Column[{Dynamic[from], Dynamic[to]}]]
```

Why my `Column[{Dynamic[from], Dynamic[to]}]]` doesn't work?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Feyre When I change my directory,the `Column[{Dynamic[from], Dynamic[to]}]]` will change too.

Comment: `DynamicModule` is a "rectangle on a screen", by using `Print` you are throwing stuff away from that rectangle before the scoping procedure is finished. You can combine Grid and Column with another Column. Or you can `Print` from `Initialization` but you need to add `DynamicModule[{}, Grid..., InheritScope -> True]`.

Comment: The real question is what is the flow you are trying to achieve? What do you want the user to see and when.

Comment: p.s. must read: tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality

Comment: Have to agree with @Kuba, I think that's one of the most useful tutorials available to a Mathematica user (as well as [tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html))

Comment: @yode so, what would you like at achieve at the end? What exactly should happen?

Comment: @Kuba this is what I want exactly,`MyCopy1 := 
 DynamicModule[{f}, 
  DynamicModule[{from, to}, 
   Print@{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from], "Directory"], 
     f = Dynamic[from]};
   Dynamic[f]]]`,the last `Dynamic[f]` will take effect.But I don't know,why `MyCopy2:=DynamicModule[{f},DynamicModule[{from,to},Print@{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from],"Directory"],f=Dynamic[from]};
FileNames["*",Dynamic[f]]]]` will don't work still,confusing very much.

Comment: @yode I'm not asking what code you want. I'm asking what do you want the user to see, what should happen and when/after what user action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my code wait until two actions are done?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134104/how-can-i-make-my-code-wait-until-two-actions-are-done)