# How can I make my code wait until two actions are done?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, interactive

This question was inspired by yode's question found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134039/3066). I think yode asked the wrong question, so I am asking what I think is the right one.

Consider a situation in which the user has to choose two directories before a computation can move forward. We want to present the user with two file-name setters but have the code wait until the user has chosen one directory from each setter before proceeding. How can we do that?

Comment: If you have time, could you please check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141888/12) for grammar and clarity?

Comment: @Szabolcs. I didn't find anything wrong with the grammar, but I have made what I hope is a clarification. Do you think it clear now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

My answer is to use `Dynamic` with the option `UpdateInterval -> 1` to hold the code that checks the completion condition.

```
DynamicModule[{from, to},
  Column[
   {Dynamic @
      Row[
        {FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from], "Directory", Appearance -> "From where"],
         FileNameSetter[Dynamic[to], "Directory", Appearance -> "To where"],
         Button["Reset", Clear[from, to]]}],
    Dynamic[
      If[And @@ {ValueQ[from], ValueQ[to]}, 
        StringJoin[{from, "  ", to}], "Waiting ..."],
      UpdateInterval -> 1]}]]
```

Before the condition is fulfilled, the user sees

[image: before]

After the condition is fulfilled, the user sees

[image: after]

The **Reset** button lets the code be reused to pick another pair of directories.

Comment: Thanks.Good workaround,I think the `Column` save me. :)