# How can I install packages distributed as .paclet files?

Tags: packages, installation, paclets

I downloaded a Mathematica package. It came as a file with the `.paclet` extension. How can I install or uninstall it?

Comment: This question exists so that people who distribute their packages as paclets can direct users here for installation instructions. If you find that the answer is not clear enough, feel free to improve it—it's community wiki. But please keep it concise.

Comment: Congratulations on Legendary! :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow, thanks!  If you don't point it out, I would not have noticed ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

***Update:*** The paclet-related functionality [is documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Paclets.html) in Mathematica 12.1. See [`PacletInstall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PacletInstall.html).

---

This answer is for people who are not interested in package development, and just need to install a Mathematica package which they obtained as a `.paclet` file.

**Note:** Before using the functions in this guide, it may be necessary to evaluate `` Needs["PacletManager`"] ``. Specifically, this is needed when your notebooks's default context is set to "Unique to This Notebook".

### Installing

Packages distributed as paclets can be installed using the `PacletInstall` function.  Evaluate this function with its argument the full path to the downloaded `.paclet` file.

For example, if `SomePackage-1.0.0.paclet` was downloaded into the `~/Downloads` directory, then evaluate

```
PacletInstall["~/Downloads/SomePackage-1.0.0.paclet"]
```

You may use Insert → File Path... to easily insert the path to this file.

### Getting information

`.paclet` files are typically named as `SomePackage-1.0.0.paclet`. Here `SomePackage` is the paclet name and `1.0.0` is its version.  To get information about the active version of a currently installed paclet, use `PacletInformation` with its name:

```
PacletInformation["SomePackage"]
```

To list all installed versions of a paclet, use

```
PacletFind["SomePackage"]
```

Typically the latest version will be the active one. This is listed first by `PacletFind`.

### Uninstalling

To uninstall all versions of a paclet named `SomePackage`, use

```
PacletUninstall["SomePackage"]
```

**Warning:** Mathematica uses many system paclets. Do not attempt to uninstall these. Only uninstall paclets that you have installed yourself.

### Paclets with documentation

Packages that come with documentation may show up in the Documentation Center's Add-ons browser.  Open the Documentation through the Help menu and look for the *Add-ons and Packages* link in the lower right corner:

[image]

Clicking it will show a list of those installed packages (both paclets and traditional ones) that come with documentation. The list may have buttons for opening the package's documentation or for uninstalling it.

### Information for developers

If you are looking to distribute your own packages as paclets, read the following threads:

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12)
- [PacletInfo.m documentation project](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12)

Comment: What does `PacletUninstall` actually do, besides deleting the indicated paclet in `$UserBaseDirectory/Paclets/Repository`(to abuse a notation)? that is, is some database elsewhere in `$UserBaseDirectory` also modified? (And why did Wolfram have to use the name "paclet". which drives my auto-spell-correction crazy, insisting on changing it to "packet" each time I type it?!)

Comment: @murray I do not know. I always assumed that it also updates some database (perhaps those .pmd files).

Comment: @murray On a cursory inspection, it seems to delete that directory, then do something similar to `RebuildPacletData[]` (which is the function that modifies databases).  I didn't dig deeper. It's late here, going to bed ...

Comment: Strange that there's no documentation on `PacletUninstall` and `PacletInstall` -- unless Wolfram doesn't really want 3rd parties to distribute adding in the form of paclets.

Comment: @murray These functions have been around for a very long time (maybe v6?), but they were originally meant for internal use only. They are still officially undocumented, but now there are [examples coming directly from WRI](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/) that use the paclet format.  I no longer feel that using these functions is a bad idea, and I wouldn't be surprised if they became officially supported and documented in the future.