# Installing a Paclet from GitHub (or other non-paclet server site)

Tags: paclets

How can I install a package from GitHub as a [paclet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/how-to-distribute-mathematica-packages-as-paclets)?

Can such a process be formulated in general?

Answer (score 9):

### Preamble

Note that this is a special case. If the developer provides you with a paclet file already you can just install that by URL. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141887/how-can-i-install-packages-distributed-as-paclet-files) for more

This is all built into my [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net/) service connection. You can get that [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/paclets/PacletServer/main.html#ServiceConnection_PackageData) or by running

```
PacletInstall["ServiceConnection_PackageData",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

If you just want to look at the package itself it's on GitHub https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools

The basic strategy is this:

- Download the files (for GitHub, check for releases / clone the repo)
- Check the directory layout to see if it's already a paclet. If not, rebuild the directory slightly so that it can be treated as such.
- Call `PackPaclet` then `PacletInstall`

---

### Case 1: Properly Formatted Paclets

So *if* the repo is laid out properly as a paclet this is easy.

Simply clone the repo:

```
With[{
  dir =
   FileNameJoin@{
     $TemporaryDirectory,
     DeleteCases[URLParse[loc, "Path"], ""][[2]]
     }
  },
 Quiet[
  DeleteDirectory[dir, DeleteContents -> True];
  CreateDirectory[dir]
  ];
 RunProcess[{"git", "clone", loc, dir}];
 dir
 ]
```

Call [`PackPaclet`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/PacletManager/ref/PackPaclet.html) on it

And call [`PacletInstall`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/PacletManager/ref/PacletInstall.html) on that

#### Case 1.1: Releases

But maybe the creator of the repository provides releases for us (e.g. [Szabolcs](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases/tag/v0.3.0)). If that's the case, we'll want to find the most recent of these for release and use that. So we can generalize this pull process:

```
gitPacletPull[loc : (_String | _URL | _File)] :=

  If[StringContainsQ[URLParse[loc, "PathString"], "releases"],
   Block[{
     release =
      SelectFirst[
       Flatten@{
         Import[
          URLBuild@
             ReplacePart[#, {
               "Domain" -> "api.github.com",
               "Path" ->
                With[{cleanpath = DeleteCases[#["Path"], ""]},
                 If[cleanpath[[1]] === "repos",
                  cleanpath,
                  Prepend[cleanpath, "repos"]
                  ]
                 ]
               }] &@URLParse[loc],
          "RawJSON"]},
       KeyMemberQ[#, "assets"] || 
         KeyMemberQ[#, 
           "zipball_url"] &&
            (#["prerelease"] =!= True) &
       ]
     },
    If[AssociationQ@release,
     With[{tmp = CreateDirectory[]},
      First@MinimalBy[FileNameDepth]@Select[DirectoryQ]@
         If[
          KeyMemberQ[release, "assets"] && 
           Length@release["assets"] > 0,
          With[{url =
             release[["assets", -1, "browser_download_url"]]
            },
           ExtractArchive[
            URLDownload[url,
             FileNameJoin@{
               $TemporaryDirectory,
               URLParse[url, "Path"][[-1]]
               }
             ],
            tmp
            ]
           ],
          ExtractArchive[
           URLDownload[
            release["zipball_url"],
            FileNameJoin@{
              $TemporaryDirectory,
              URLParse[release["zipball_url"], "Path"][[-1]]
              }
            ],
           tmp
           ]
          ]
      ],
     $Failed
     ]
    ],
   With[{
     dir =
      FileNameJoin@{
        $TemporaryDirectory,
        DeleteCases[URLParse[loc, "Path"], ""][[2]]
        }
     },
    Quiet[
     DeleteDirectory[dir, DeleteContents -> True];
     CreateDirectory[dir]
     ];
    RunProcess[{"git", "clone", loc, dir}];
    dir
    ]
   ];
```

---

### Case 2: Unformatted Paclet

If not, we'll need to auto-detect the layout. There's a lot of code here (much of it treating various special cases), but it's all worth having. Basically it tries to detect the paclet layout and, if it fails to do so, makes the layout appropriate for a paclet. The corner case of just having all the code in a notebook is just to make a package that'll reopen a copy of that notebook when the paclet is called.

Note that it calls things like `PDexpressionBundle` which auto-create a [`"PacletInfo.m"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/pacletinfo-m-documentation-project). They're essentially just copies of the definitions [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/PacletTools.m).

```
Options[installPacletGenerate] = {
   "Verbose" -> False
   };

installPacletGenerate[dir : (_String | _File)?DirectoryQ, 
   ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{bundleDir = dir},
   If[OptionValue@"Verbose",
    DisplayTemporary@
     Internal`LoadingPanel[
      TemplateApply["Bundling PDpaclet for ``", dir]
      ]
    ];
   (* ------------ Extract Archive Files --------------- *)

   If[FileExistsQ@#, Quiet@ExtractArchive[#, dir]] & /@
    Map[
     FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName@dir <> #} &,
     {".zip", ".gz"}
     ];
   (* ------------ Detect Paclet Layout --------------- *)
   Which[
    FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, "PacletInfo.m"},
    bundleDir = dir,
    FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName[dir] <> ".m"} ||

     FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName[dir] <> ".wl"} ||

       FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, "Kernel", "init" <> ".m"} ||

       FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, "Kernel", "init" <> ".wl"},
    bundleDir = dir;
    PDpacletExpressionBundle[bundleDir],
    FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName@dir, "PacletInfo.m"},
    bundleDir = FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName@dir},
    FileExistsQ@
     FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName@dir, FileBaseName@dir <> ".m"},
    bundleDir = FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName@dir};
    PDpacletExpressionBundle[bundleDir],
    FileExistsQ@FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName[dir] <> ".nb"},
    Export[
     FileNameJoin@{dir, FileBaseName[dir] <> ".m"},
     "(*Open package notebook*)
     CreateDocument[
        Import@
            StringReplace[$InputFileName,\".m\"->\".nb\"]
      ]",
     "Text"
     ];
    bundleDir = dir;
    PDpacletExpressionBundle[bundleDir],
    _,
    Message[PDInstallPaclet::laywha];
    Throw[$Failed]
    ];
   PDpacletBundle[bundleDir]
   ];

installPacletGenerate[file : (_String | _File)?FileExistsQ, 
   ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Switch[FileExtension[file],
   "m" | "wl",
   If[OptionValue@"Verbose",
    DisplayTemporary@
     Internal`LoadingPanel[
      TemplateApply["Bundling PDpaclet for ``", file]
      ]
    ];
   With[{dir =
      FileNameJoin@{
        $TemporaryDirectory,
        FileBaseName@file
        }
     },
    Quiet@CreateDirectory[dir];
    If[FileExistsQ@
      FileNameJoin@{
        DirectoryName@file,
        "DependencyInfo.m"
        },
     CopyFile[
      FileNameJoin@{
        DirectoryName@file,
        "DependencyInfo.m"
        },
      FileNameJoin@{
        dir,
        "DependencyInfo.m"
        } 
      ]
     ];
    If[FileExistsQ@
      FileNameJoin@{
        DirectoryName@file,
        "PacletInfo.m"
        },
     CopyFile[
      FileNameJoin@{
        DirectoryName@file,
        "PacletInfo.m"
        },
      FileNameJoin@{
        dir,
        "PacletInfo.m"
        } 
      ]
     ];
    CopyFile[file,
     FileNameJoin@{
       dir,
       FileNameTake@file
       },
     OverwriteTarget -> True
     ];
    PDpacletExpressionBundle[dir,
     "Name" ->
      StringReplace[FileBaseName[dir],
       Except[WordCharacter | "$"] -> ""]
     ];
    PDpacletBundle[dir,
     "BuildRoot" -> $TemporaryDirectory
     ]
    ],
   "nb",
   With[{dir =
      FileNameJoin@{
        $TemporaryDirectory,
        StringJoin@RandomSample[Alphabet[], 10],
        FileBaseName@file
        }
     },
    Quiet[
     DeleteDirectory[dir, DeleteContents -> True];
     CreateDirectory[dir, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]
     ];
    CopyFile[file, FileNameJoin@{dir, FileNameTake@file}];
    installPacletGenerate[dir]
    ],
   "PDpaclet",
   file,
   _,
   Message[PDInstallPaclet::howdo,
    FileExtension@file
    ]
   ];
```

---

### General Case:

And so generally what we'll want is to pull down the paclet with `gitPacletPull` or another appropriate pull function (I also wrote one for the Wolfram Library Archive) and then format it with `installPacletGenerate` before calling `PacletInstall`.

This process is built into `PDInstallPaclet`

For example:

```
PackageDataFunction`PDInstallPaclet[
  "https://github.com/b3m2a1/TestPaclet"];
<< TestPaclet`
```

gives me:

[image: test-paclet-image]

Or

```
PackageDataFunction`PDInstallPaclet["https://github.com/szhorvat/\
IGraphM/releases"]

{
PacletManager`Paclet[
 "Name" -> "IGraphM", "Version" -> "0.3.91", 
  "MathematicaVersion" -> "10.0+", 
  "Description" -> "IGraph/M \[Dash] the igraph interface for \
Mathematica.", "Creator" -> "Szabolcs Horvát <szhorvat@gmail.com>", 
  "URL" -> "http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM", 
  "Thumbnail" -> "Logo.png", 
  "SystemID" -> {
   "MacOSX-x86-64", "Windows-x86-64", "Linux-x86-64", "Linux-ARM"}, 
  "Extensions" -> {{
    "Kernel", "Root" -> ".", "Context" -> "IGraphM`"}, {
    "LibraryLink"}, {
    "Documentation", "MainPage" -> "IGDocumentation"}}, 
  "Location" -> "~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/\
IGraphM-0.3.91"]}
```

Comment: The first code block fails

Comment: For me, the first code block returns a PacletObject[ ]. How do I use that object?