# need simple example of setting up gitlink

Tags: packages, gitlink

```
<< GitLink`
```

produces the following error

> InitializeGitLibrary::libnotfound: -- Message text not found --

then

```
GitOpen["C:\\Users\\atfai\\Desktop\\Version Control System\\Local Repository"]
```

> $Failed

what is going on?

https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink

Comment: Have you installed the `paclet` that you find under releases? This looks like you just copied the source files without compiled libraries.

Comment: Thank you gitlink now works by installing paclet. But i am getting the new error what does it mean by tree was invalid?

Comment: If you have another question, ask another one. Do not change existing topic because the answer became invalid. I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once started [`` MPM` `` project](https://github.com/kubaPod/MPM), currently it is not high on my todo list but will help here:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubapod/mpm/master/install.m"] 
Needs @ "MPM`"
MPMInstall["WolframResearch", "GitLink"]
```

> ```
> Paclet[MPM,0.5.1,<>]
> ```
>
> Searching for assets WolframResearch/GitLink/latest
>
> Downloading GitLink-2016.10.21.06.paclet...
>
> Installing GitLink-2016.10.21.06.paclet...
>
> ```
> Paclet[GitLink,2016.10.21.06,<>]
> ```

```
<< GitLink`
```

For manual installation see [GitLink Readme.md](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/blob/master/Readme.md)

Alternatively, take a look at [b3m2a1's `PDInstallPaclet`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152660/5478)

Comment: Thank you it works!