# How does PacletInstall work? And is it possible to find packages using PacletInstall?

Tags: packages, documentation

It seems that many packages published could be installed using **PacletInstall** 
. For example, from this [Rubi install instruction](https://rulebasedintegration.org/downloadRubi.html) webpage, we could see the comman:

```
PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]
```

and the package then would be downloaded and installed automatically.

How does this function works? And it seems there is not documentation that describe this function in documentation center. And is it possible to find a third party package(for example, I'd like to find a package that relevant to formula-manipulation) that I need to use **PacletInstall** or relative function like that?

Comment: Check [this](https://mresources.github.io/tutorial/package-usage-and-development/basics/paclets.html) nice doc by @b3m2a1

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want to know how to use this function? Do you want to know how to make your package installable with this function? Take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141887/12 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12, respectively.

Comment: If you want to find packages, look at http://packagedata.net/ or https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/

Comment: @Szabolcs Maybe I should ask the questions separately. First, I want to know the principle or internal workflow of Pacletinstall , not merely how to use it. The second is that I wonder if there is a package focus on commonly formula or algebra expression manipulate when I found a excellent code here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/62528

Comment: What would you gain from knowing how it's implemented? It sounds like you are not asking about what you actually want to know. Anyway, you can read the code at `SystemOpen@
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Autoload", 
   "PacletManager"}]`